# openSUSE: install alternate version of python without changing default version

Tags: python, linux, versioning, opensuse

I'm running openSUSE 13.2. I already had python 2.7.8 and python 3.4.x. I ran into a situation where a business server was running python 2.6. I wanted to make a virtualenv, but I need to install the specific version first. I couldn't find python 2.6 in yast and I wasn't getting any hits when I was search for stuff in zypper.

So I downloaded the tar ball from python's download page for python 2.6.6 and followed the directions in the readme

1. ./configure
2. sudo make install

This worked, but it changed my default python interpreter in the process. I worked through that and now things are fine. But I  might want to install a different python version in the future without having to worry about it changing my default interpreter. I'm pretty sure there's more I could do on my own, but I need to move on to something else and I'm wondering if anybody was some quick feedback on what I've done so far and what I should do in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to maintain distinct versions simultaneously, it's best to install each in its own tree. `configure` takes an optional `--prefix=/path/to/installation/root` argument.

At one site, we would install an add-on software package in something like `/opt/local/x86_64-linux-gnu/python-2.6.6`. Users who need this specific version can then add `/opt/local/x86_64-linux-gnu/python-2.6.6/bin` to their `$PATH`, or use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

Comment: Will the inclusion of the --prefix argument prevent the alias 'python' from getting overwritten?

Comment: Installing from Python source tarballs will not alter shell aliases, nor will it change the symlinks maintained by [alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives). It will only overwrite the file tree specified in the `--prefix` option (the default prefix is `/usr/local`).

Comment: In that case, I'm going to have to go back and revisit what I did. I must have done something else to affect that.